# how to sum up by hour in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

For example, I have a table1(This is just a part of table1,table1 actually have 57000 records, starttime ranges from 2014-04-08 23:59:56 to 2014-04-09 23:59:56 ):

```
+---------------------+
| StartTime           |
+---------------------+
| 2014-04-08 23:59:56 |
| 2014-04-08 23:59:59 |
| 2014-04-09 00:00:03 |
| 2014-04-09 00:00:03 |
| 2014-04-09 00:00:05 |
| 2014-04-09 00:00:08 |
| 2014-04-09 00:00:09 |
| 2014-04-09 00:00:11 |
| 2014-04-09 00:00:11 |
| 2014-04-09 00:00:17 |
+---------------------+
```

This table is about network flows, start time means the start time of each flow's.Some network flows have same start time. I want to calculate how many flows in each hour.
pseudo-code is like

```
select count(starttime) as totalPerHour from table1 group by hour; 
(just pseudo-code)
The result should be:
  TimestampHOUR       totalPerHour
  2014-04-09 01:00       46
  2014-04-09 02:00       3
  2014-04-09 03:00       55
  2014-04-09 04:00       12
  2014-04-09 05:00       2369
  2014-04-09 06:00       99
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

combine Hour(...) and Count(..)

```
select hour(StartTime), count(StartTime)
from table1
group by hour(StartTime)
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has [`hour(..)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour). Use it something like:

```
select count(*) as totalPerHour from table1 group by HOUR(StartTime);
```